# Is linking to primary sources or secondary sources better for SEO?

Tags: seo, links

Okay, so here is a question based on my old-school journalism training/knowledge versus my modern web developer knowledge.

Does using primary sources for a linked URL versus a secondary source have any impact on SEO?

For example, I write a blog post about a major event of some kind. It’s reported in *The New York Times* which is a high quality primary news source. But a quick Google search on this even shows tons of smaller blogs reporting the same event with details and quotes and a link to that article in the *The New York Times*.

If I were to post a new post on my blog on that same event, would my SEO suffer if I use a secondary source blog as the link versus the primary source article from *The New York Times*?

From a traditional journalism perspective, citing the primary source is the way to go. But from a modern blog/SEO perspective does that even matter? I assume not only is *The New York Times* better regarded as a source, but the chances of the reference link going dead are far less when compared to some random blog that might disappear at some point in the future.

Comment: Who you link to matters. Link to high or reasonably high quality sites only. Link to the highest quality site where there are options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that much *to your site* if you link to a reasonably good quality blog versus the *New York Times*. But it may matter a lot to the blog you linked to!

Google addressed your specific issue in their Webmaster Central Blog back in 2008. It remains [good advice](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/10/linking-out-often-its-just-applying.html):

> *Should I worry about the sites I choose to link to? What if their PageRank may be lower than mine?*
>
> If you're linking to content you believe your users will enjoy, then please don't worry about the site's perceived PageRank. As a webmaster, the things to be wary of regarding outbound links are listed above, such as losing credibility by linking to spammy sites. Otherwise, consider outbound links as a common sense way to provide more value to your users, not a complicated formula.

The only sorts of links that will really harm you are [unnatural links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604774), which are paid links without a nofollow tag, [link schemes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356), and the like.

---

What I recommend you do is simply to link to the source you intend to cite. If you're quoting or referring to *Times* coverage of a story, then link to them. If you're quoting or referring to Jimbo's East Tennessee Politics and Shooting Blog, then linking to the *Times* is rather pointless; you should link to Jimbo. If you're referring to a *Times* story that you read about on Jimbo's blog, then you can link to the *Times* story and note that you read about it on Jimbo's blog (with a link).

Comment: Makes sense. Poor Jimbo! :/

Comment: @JakeGould If Jimbo is something your readers should also be reading, I am sure you can find a way to work him in to your story.

Comment: I’ll be sure to add a Jimbo-based initiative to our action list.

Comment: @JakeGould By way of example, I was once [quoted in this manner by USA TODAY](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/politics/election2008/2008-01-02-paul_N.htm). Unfortuntately they didn't do outbound links at that time, but I still picked up plenty of traffic just by having my blog named in the story.